# Change Windows 10 Background Solid Color in Python

Tags: python, windows, colors, desktop, wallpaper

I am aware that with `ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, pathToImage, 3)` I can change the wallpaper image and by setting the `pathToImage` to an empty string I would effectively have no image as wallpaper, thus I will see the *solid background color*.

My question is, **How to change the solid background color**?

---

#### Edit #1

Further investigating the Windows API. I found [IDesktopWallpaper setbackgroundcolor()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-idesktopwallpaper-setbackgroundcolor) method which sounds like something that I need. However, I am not aware how to call/use it via python or command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using [IDesktopWallpaper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-idesktopwallpaper), it is more simpler to use [SetSysColors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setsyscolors) (from `winuser.h` header).

In Python, the code would look like this:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes.wintypes import RGB
from ctypes import byref, c_int

def changeSystemColor(color)
    ctypes.windll.user32.SetSysColors(1, byref(c_int(1)), byref(c_int(color)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    color = RGB(255, 0, 0) # red
    changeColor(color)
```

As stated in your post, you can do `ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, "", 3)` to remove the wallpaper image, exposing the solid background color that you can set with `ctypes.windll.user32.SetSysColors`.

Comment: In your code, you `def`ine `changeSystemColor`, but you call `changeColor`. Also, your function definition is missing a `:`